# Flutter apps won't debug in VScode

Tags: debugging, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

After I had factory reset my MacBook Air(2019) and reinstalled flutter my apps wont start/debug. When I start debugging, both the IOS and Android emulators would start, but after that the app doesn't launch and the debug console would be empty. The debug banner would also disappear if I press restart. I then went on to install bash and all the other command line tools flutter needed because I remembered that OS Catalina had migrated over to zsh, but that didn't fix the issue either.

Also when I performed the factory reset I erased/formatted the Macintosh-HD partition along with the Macintosh-data partition

At this point I think I might have deleted something I shouldn't have, because I can't find any errors within my environment.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I am not expert at all, but have you tried running flutter clean?

Comment: Yup, nothing changed sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem and solved cleaning and resolving dependencies again on terminal:

```
$ flutter clean

$ flutter pub get
```

Then click on Start with Debugging.